# Spring mvc rest, json and xml output contain the package name

Tags: json, spring-mvc, xml-serialization

We need to support XML and JSON output from a objects, I have a List which i display in json and xml format, the problem i am facing is it also shows the underlying class, below i am showing all part of codes starting with 
output
domain objects
configuration &
controller

```
**XML Output**

    "<**com.bookstore.Books**> Unwanted
    <books>
    <com.bookstore.Book>
    <name>book0</name>
    </com.bookstore.Book>
    <com.bookstore.Book>
    <name>book1</name>
    </com.bookstore.Book>
    </books>
    </com.bookstore.Books>" 


    **JSON Output** Unwanted part is in bold

    **"org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.books**" 
    :[{"isbn":"03601","authors":[{"autho

    I have defind book class as
    @XStreamAlias("book")
    public class Book {....}
    and Books
    @XStreamAlias("books")
    public class Books {...

List<Book> books;
```

**The context settings are like this**

```
 <beans:bean id="xmlView"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
      <beans:constructor-arg>
         <beans:bean class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller">
            <beans:property name="autodetectAnnotations" value="true"/>
         </beans:bean>
      </beans:constructor-arg>
   </beans:bean>
   <beans:bean id="jsonView"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView">
   </beans:bean> 
   <beans:bean id="jsonConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
   </beans:bean>
```

**The controller part is :**

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/books/xml")
        public ModelAndView getAllBooksXML() {
            List<Book> books = bookService.getAllBooks();
            ModelAndView mav = 
                new ModelAndView("xmlView", BindingResult.MODEL_KEY_PREFIX + "books", books);
            return mav;
        }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/books/json")
        public ModelAndView getAllBooksJson() {
            List<Book> books = bookService.getAllBooks();
            ModelAndView mav = 
                new ModelAndView("jsonView", BindingResult.MODEL_KEY_PREFIX + "books", books);
            return mav;
        }


Please let me know otherwie i will have t
```

i write a custom converter.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided seems to use XStream annotations while your spring configuration is configured to use jackson.

Have you tried the annotations supported by jackson? 
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/JacksonAnnotations